# Bounding Box selecting entire image instead of polygons

Tags: python, mask, opencv, bounding-box

I am trying to draw bounding boxes around polygon images.I orginally marked the images and created the polygon masks using a json file.

This is my code:
I use the json file to keep the names of the files constant.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

jsonFile ='/directory..../.json' 

with open(jsonFile) as file:
    annotations = json.load(file)
    
    for key in annotations:
        regions = annotations[key]['regions']
        for region in regions:
            print(annotations[key]['filename'],"\n")

            image = cv2.imread('/directory to mask images.png' + annotations[key]['filename'])
            original = image.copy()

            gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
            # Find contours, obtain bounding box, extract and save ROI
            ROI_number = 0
            cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
            for c in cnts:
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
                ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(annotations[key]['filename']), ROI)
                ROI_number += 1
            cv2.imshow('image', image)
            cv2.waitKey()
```

My problem is instead of drawing bounding boxes over the polygons in the picture, I am just outlining the border of the full image.

If it matters, the image is black and the polygon masks are white.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might come from the threshold operation. If the original image is black with white polygons, then the `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` will transform it into a white image with black polygons. Since the contour function finds the polygons surrounding the white space, the resulting polygon will surround the whole image. In order to fix this, just use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` instead of `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`.

Comment: As an addendum, if the image you're loading is already a mask, you might not even need to use the `cv2.threshold` function